# How to extract values from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I extract a particular number from the below array values between two underscores

```
names = [ "create_sales_3920_7873","create_sales_49204_7873","create_sales_392_7873"]
```

How to get output result as 3920, 49204, 392 from the above array

Any help is appreciable

Comment: Do the array elements always start with ```"create_sales_"``` and do they always end with ```"_7873"```?  Or do they at least always end with an underscore followed by 4 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual `names` array is quite long I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but looping over the array and using [split](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) will get the job done for the example you've posted:

```
names = [ "create_sales_3920_7873","create_sales_49204_7873","create_sales_392_7873"]


# initialize empty results array
output = []

# iterate over each string in array
names.each do |name|
  # use split to grab substring and add to results array
 output << name.split(/create_sales_/).last.split(/_/).first
end

#confirm result => ["3920", "49204", "392"]
puts output
```

Answer (score 2):

```
names = [
  "create_sales_3920_7873",
  "create_sales_49204_7873",
  "create_sales_392_7873"
]
```

```
names.map { |s| s[/(?<=_)\d+(?=_)/] }
  #=> ["3920", "49204", "392"]
```

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

`(?<=_)` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the match is immediately preceded by an underscore.

`\d+` matches one or more digits, as many as possible.

`(?=_)/` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match is immediately followed by an underscore.

The regular expression therefore matches the first sequence of digits in the string that is preceded and followed by an underscore.

---

In a comment @3limin4t0r suggested

```
names.map { |s| s[/_(\d+)_/, 1] }
```

as an alternative.

We see that for the same strings [`s[/(?<=_)\d+(?=_)/]`](https://regex101.com/r/Jw0gww/1) requires 936 steps and takes 3.2ms to execute, whereas [`[/_(\d+)_/, 1]`](https://regex101.com/r/sGYtSE/1) takes only 324 steps and 0.3ms. That seems pretty clear-cut.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `names.map { |name| name[/_(\d+)_/, 1] }`. Capturing the desired result in capture group 1 and using it as the return value.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, good point. I have an irrational preference for matching without capturing, just like I can't bring myself to use `compact`.